# Ionic: How to run ionic app on VMware workstation player

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I am working on the `ionic 1` framework.

I have built an android application, and it's working fine on android devices, but also I need to run application on `iOS`.

I have tried to install `VM-ware Workstation 12 Player` and also install `X-Code`.

How to run an app on it, as my app is on windows.

Also I have tried to share folders but I do not understand how run the app.

Answer (score 0):

Seems too late to reply, I hope it helps someone. I'am one of who face with problems when install new applications.

- I use Vmware version: 14
- Windows version: 10

Follow below link to install MacOs on Vmware. Please do not miss any configuration.

https://techsviewer.com/install-macos-mojave-vmware-windows/
//I downloaded this part

1. Fix Download Limit: https://techsviewer.com/fix-download-limit
2. Patch Tool & VM Tool: New Link  // Patch is important do not forget
3. Winrar: goo.gl/PQHT
4. VMware Player: Free download

After you successfully complete installation. 
Firstly install Node js

- https://nodejs.org/en/

You can install cordova via terminal (if you face to anyproblem, please read the terminal)

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/installation.html

After, install Xcode 10(worked fine).

After these all steps. You can run on iphone emulator easily.
Copy your existing ionic project to Mac and run it on terminal .

I had also copy paste problem. I could copy rar files from windows to Mac. But could'nt copy folder. After that  I connect via filezilla to mac via sftp(Active System->Sharing-Remote Login). I could make file transfer easily by filezilla. 
Other think you should be careful, When you connect your iphone to PC, you can understand connection is ok if Itunes start. If not change (VM-> Settings->Hardware->USB controller->USB compatibility 2.0).

If you succeed to complate all steps, fill free to ask any question. 
I'm sorry to not detailed to much, This is what I remembe. Search lots to overcome the errors.